# Prefab recommendations

Tags: design, prefab

I'm toying with the idea of completely [knocking and rebuilding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/extend-upwards-vs-knock-down-build-from-scratch) my house.  Does anyone here have experience with prefabs?  In my case I'd need a 2000ft2 modern but traditional-looking house (since my town has a saying on the design and they wouldn't accept ultra-modern looks).

Any pointers?  Any experiences?

Comment: A friend in highschool had this done with their house -- but rather than pay for someone to demolish it, they actually gave it to the local fire department to use for practice.  (which, based on the age of the house might not've been the best idea, as there was likely lead paint in there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term pre-fab is loosely used. There are several versions of pre-built structures, from pre-framed wall sections, to modular building block sections, all the way to completely built (interior & exterior) modular homes delivered on site in two or more sections. most manufactures of modular homes offer a wide variety of styles and floor plans. I would suggest finding a manufacturer within a couple hundred miles of your site, to limit transportation costs.  If you google "manufactured housing" it should bring you to many sources.  A typical modular home is sound, well built and can be ready to move in, in a week or less. If your prep is ready and you have your plumber, electrician and finish carpenter all lined up, the process is fairly easy.  Good luck.

Comment: Sounds good.  Any examples?  I'm having a hard time finding anything suitable.  I'm looking for a 2000-2400ft2 two-story with 1000-1200ft2 footprint.

Comment: http://www.avalonbuildingsystems.com. is an example.  Just google "modular homes" and look for builders in your area.  There are several in Maine, but probably some closer to you. Site I referenced will just give you an idea of the variety avail.